# Laravel , como exibir imagem através da classe

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, image

como faço para exibir uma imagem através do meu condigo css? é que o tema que uso as imagens como por exemplo: os banners são exibidas através da classe no style.css , abaixo está o que seria feito porem não sei como chegar com essa variável no arquivo style.css , eu até coloquei o código css dentro da tag  na view  para testar , porem não sei como misturar a variavel que recebo com css, eu devo estár errando a sintax .Pode me orientar se possível vfr , sou novo no laravel .

```css
.minhaClasseBanner {
  background: url("../../storage/{{$banners->image}}") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Os shortcodes do Blade em Laravel não funcionam em arquivos `.css`, somente arquivos de view (`.blade.php`). Neste caso, para colocar variáveis no CSS, você terá que passar usando a tag `style` do objeto na view em blade.

**styles.css**

```css
.minhaClasseBanner {
    /*background: url("../../storage/{{$banners->image}}") no-repeat center;*/
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**suaview.blade.php**

```html
<div class="minhaCLasseBanner" style="background: url("../../storage/{{$banners->image}}") no-repeat center">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Verdade da forma como você disse deu certo , porem minha variável com o caminho está com a barra invertida assim \ , eu preciso usar assim / , OBS: fiz o cadastro da imagem usando o Voyager , não sei se tem algo a ver,  preciso achar uma forma de salvar no banco com a barra assim /  ou tenho que achar uma forma de inverter a barra antes de usar? como sou novo em lavrável não faço ideia de como fazer isso .

Comment: @WebSistematizando faça uma nova pergunta com o link para essa, dizendo o novo problema e qual foi o problema anterior. Além disso, marque minha resposta como correta se ela lhe auxiliou

Answer (score 0):

```
.minhaClasseBanner {
    /*background: url{{asset("../../storage/{{$banners->image}}")}} no-repeat center;*/
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}
```